# Java & Spark : add unique incremental id to dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark

With Spark and Java, I am trying to add to an existing Dataset[Row] with n columns an Integer identify column.

I successfully added an id with  `zipWithUniqueId()` or with `zipWithIndex`, even using `monotonically_increasing_id()`. But neither one gives satisfaction.

Example : I have one dataset with 195 rows. When I use one of these three methods, i get some id like *1584156487* or *12036*. Plus, those id's are not contiguous.

What i need/want is rather simply : an Integer id column, which value goes 1 to dataset.count() foreach row, where id = 1 is followed by id = 2, etc.

How can I do that in Java/Spark ?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't give satisfaction ?

Comment: I edited my post, to be clearer.

Comment: You get that will all the method you have mentioned, that's not possible...

Comment: Ah... Not even a little trick to make this possible ? :/

Comment: I never said that. I just said that it's impossible that you get those results with those 3 methods.

Comment: I must have made some mistakes. With `monotonically_increasing_id()` which seemed to be what I want, I had an id at 0, then it was at more than 300000 so :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to use the [row_number](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#row_number()) function :

In java :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window;

df.withColumn("id", functions.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("a column")));
```

Or in scala :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window;
df.withColumn("id",row_number().over(Window.orderBy("a column")))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to use streaming data frames, you can use a udf with guid generator:

```
val generateUuid = udf(() => java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString())

// Cast the data as string (it comes in as binary by default)
val ddfStream = ddfStream.withColumn("uniqueId", generateUuid())
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scala you can do it as below.

```
 var a = dataframe.collect().zipWithIndex
    for (  b:(Row,Int)<-a){
      println(b._2) 

    }
```

Here b._2 you will get unique number starting from 0 to till count of row -1

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate a unique increasing id as below

```
val df1 = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    df.rdd.zipWithIndex.map {
  case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ index)
},
StructType(df.schema.fields :+ StructField("id", LongType, false)))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for a way to do it with Java. I find more documentation for scala, so it's kindda easy. But, I must do it with Java, and they is less documentation :/